# use Function keys as standard Function keys

Tags: macbook, refind

I have an old MacBook (running OS X 10.7) which I have setup to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using `rEFInd`.

This is working OK, but one aspect if annoying.

Function keys F1, F2 etc perform an alternate function (decrease/increase brightness). On `OS X` there is an option to use these keys as standard Function keys.

Is there some similar option under Ubuntu to use Function keys as standard Function keys?

Answer (score 0):

using `fn + Esc` toggles the behavior of the F1-F12 keys from "special function" to standard F-key behavior.

At least, I know this works on some keyboards; I am not sure about mac keyboards.